# javascript validation for radiobuttons in asp.net (interpreting legacy code)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, radio-button

I am working on an asp.net web app and am attempting to interpret legacy code created by a former developer.

My web page has 6 radio buttons

```
input type="radio" id="rbtnSearchBy1"  
input type="radio" id="rbtnSearchBy2"  
input type="radio" id="rbtnSearchBy3"  
input type="radio" id="rbtnSearchFor1"  
input type="radio" id="rbtnSearchFor2"  
input type="radio" id="rbtnSearchFor3"
```

however, when I look at the javascript validation code, I see

```
    if (!document.aspnetForm.Master$cphMainContent$rbtnSearchBy[0].checked) {
        if (document.aspnetForm.Master$cphMainContent$rbtnSearchBy[1].checked) {
            if (document.aspnetForm.Master$cphMainContent$rbtnSearchFor[1].checked || document.aspnetForm.Master$cphMainContent$rbtnSearchFor[2].checked) {
                document.aspnetForm.Master$cphMainContent$rbtnSearchBy[0].checked = true;
                ValidateUserFields()
                alert("Please select either location or facility name.");
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (document.aspnetForm.Master$cphMainContent$rbtnSearchFor[0].checked) {
                document.aspnetForm.Master$cphMainContent$rbtnSearchBy[0].checked = true;
                ValidateUserFields()
                alert("Please select either location or vendor name.");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

and I cannot understand what **rbtnSearchBy[0]** or **rbtnSearchFor[0]** would be for ?
Any suggestions?